# Conditional addition of New Layer based upon front Layer - Photoshop CC 2017 JS Script JSX

Tags: javascript, if-statement, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I am trying to add a condition to this script which I created from another photoshop action using `Action to JSX Script`.

Normally my PSDs have at least two layers. **1st layer** is a **(unwanted)** partial mirror image of a **(wanted)** **second layer**. This script select the unwanted 1st layer and remove it and do some other actions on remaining layer and create a jpg. My second layer contain required image.

However, If 1st layer is not a partial mirror image of second layer, as there is no mirror image layer exist then I don't want to remove 1st layer as it contain required image in it.

In this situation I want to create a new blank helping layer on top of this 1st layer to make it second layer then my script do as usual as it does, i.e. remove unwanted 1st layer and do other actions on remaining layer.

**So to achieve this I want conditional addition of New Layer based upon front Layer. In my mind I have a condition which should trigger addition of a new layer:**

- If 1st layer is 60% to 70% filled with some image, then it add a layer otherwise proceed to next line.

Here is example:
Canvas Size 2K x 2K pixel
[image: Canvas Size 2K x 2K pixel]
80% Empty Canvas (2K x 2K) from Front Layer, Pixel Layer Properties> 375px X 130px
[image: Pixel Layer Properties> 375px X 130px are taking only ~20% of Canvas]

How to incorporated this condition to my JS script between 18 and 19 line. I have checked `photoshop cc javascript ref 2015` but I didn't understand how to incorporate this condition to my script.

```js
#target photoshop
//
// Conditional Layer Removal PSD JPG.jsx
// Conditional Removal of ID Layer based upon number of layer in a PSD

//
// Generated Sat Jul 29 2017 00:59:28 GMT+0500
//

cTID = function(s) { return app.charIDToTypeID(s); };
sTID = function(s) { return app.stringIDToTypeID(s); };
var layerCount = app.activeDocument.layers.length;
    if (layerCount > 2)
    {
//
//==================== RemoveIDLayer ==============
//
function RemoveIDLayer() {
  // Select
  function step1(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
      return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    ref1.putEnumerated(cTID('Lyr '), cTID('Ordn'), cTID('Frnt'));
    desc1.putReference(cTID('null'), ref1);
    desc1.putBoolean(cTID('MkVs'), false);
    var list1 = new ActionList();
    list1.putInteger(9);
    desc1.putList(cTID('LyrI'), list1);
    executeAction(cTID('slct'), desc1, dialogMode);
  };

  // Delete
  function step2(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
      return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    ref1.putEnumerated(cTID('Lyr '), cTID('Ordn'), cTID('Trgt'));
    desc1.putReference(cTID('null'), ref1);
    var list1 = new ActionList();
    list1.putInteger(9);
    desc1.putList(cTID('LyrI'), list1);
    executeAction(cTID('Dlt '), desc1, dialogMode);
  };

  // Select
  function step3(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
      return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    ref1.putEnumerated(cTID('Lyr '), cTID('Ordn'), cTID('Frnt'));
    desc1.putReference(cTID('null'), ref1);
    desc1.putBoolean(cTID('MkVs'), false);
    var list1 = new ActionList();
    list1.putInteger(9);
    desc1.putList(cTID('LyrI'), list1);
    executeAction(cTID('slct'), desc1, dialogMode);
  };

  // Trim
  function step4(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
      return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc1.putEnumerated(sTID("trimBasedOn"), sTID("trimBasedOn"), sTID("topLeftPixelColor"));
    desc1.putBoolean(cTID('Top '), true);
    desc1.putBoolean(cTID('Btom'), true);
    desc1.putBoolean(cTID('Left'), true);
    desc1.putBoolean(cTID('Rght'), true);
    executeAction(sTID('trim'), desc1, dialogMode);
  };

  // Trim
  function step5(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
      return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc1.putEnumerated(sTID("trimBasedOn"), sTID("trimBasedOn"), sTID("bottomRightPixelColor"));
    desc1.putBoolean(cTID('Top '), true);
    desc1.putBoolean(cTID('Btom'), true);
    desc1.putBoolean(cTID('Left'), true);
    desc1.putBoolean(cTID('Rght'), true);
    executeAction(sTID('trim'), desc1, dialogMode);
  };

    // Scripts
  function step6(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
      return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var estr = '//@include "~/OneDrive/Business/Website Making/Commands and Scripts/Adobe Scripts/Conditional resizeImage 1100 All.jsx";\r\n';
    eval(estr);
  };

// Canvas Size
  function step7(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
      return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc1.putBoolean(cTID('Rltv'), true);
    desc1.putUnitDouble(cTID('Wdth'), cTID('#Pxl'), 300);
    desc1.putUnitDouble(cTID('Hght'), cTID('#Pxl'), 300);
    desc1.putEnumerated(cTID('Hrzn'), cTID('HrzL'), cTID('Cntr'));
    desc1.putEnumerated(cTID('Vrtc'), cTID('VrtL'), cTID('Cntr'));
    desc1.putEnumerated(sTID("canvasExtensionColorType"), sTID("canvasExtensionColorType"), cTID('BckC'));
    executeAction(sTID('canvasSize'), desc1, dialogMode);
  };

// Scripts
  function step8(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
      return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var estr = '//@include "~/OneDrive/Business/Website Making/Commands and Scripts/Adobe Scripts/PSDtoJPG.jsx";\r\n';
    eval(estr);
  };

  // Close
  function step9(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
      return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc1.putEnumerated(cTID('Svng'), cTID('YsN '), cTID('N   '));
    desc1.putInteger(cTID('DocI'), 816);
    desc1.putBoolean(sTID("forceNotify"), true);
    executeAction(cTID('Cls '), desc1, dialogMode);
  };

  step1();      // Select
  step2();      // Delete
  step3();      // Select
  step4();      // Trim
  step5();      // Trim
  step6();      // Scripts
  step7();      // Canvas Size
  step8();      // Scripts
  step9();      // Close
};



//=========================================
//                    RemoveIDLayer.main
//=========================================
//

RemoveIDLayer.main = function () {
  RemoveIDLayer();
};

RemoveIDLayer.main();

// EOF

"Conditional Layer Removal PSD JPG.jsx"
// EOF
    }
else app.doAction ("< 2 Layer removal PSD", "My Actions")
```

Comment: What does "If 1st layer is 60% to 70% filled with some image, then it add a layer otherwise proceed to next line" mean exactly? The layer fills the image but has 60-70% opacity? The layer occupies 60-70% of the area of the image? If the latter what about layer content outside of the image area?

Comment: Sorry for so late. I was sick. No, reverse of latter condition. If an image occupies 60% to 70% of front layer area (i.e. front layer has 30% to 40% empty space) then add new layer on top of it. otherwise proceed to next line of code.

Comment: I still don't think we understand what you mean by "empty." Can you further elaborate?

Comment: here is an example of empty space.
`Canvas Size`: 2000px * 2000px;
Front Layer `Image Size`: 2000px * 2000px;
`Photoshop 2017 CC or latest` >> Windows >> Workspace >> Essentials >> `select` Front Layer >> Right side second last vertical panel >> `Properties` >> `Pixel Layer Properties` W: 1275px H: 1832px. Here you can see at 2000 px wide canvas front layer pixel width is 1275px, which I translate into filled 80% of canvas or 20% empty canvas.

Comment: I have photo added.